# Using STS, how to add application context

Tags: java, spring, maven, applicationcontext

I need some help with setting up a spring project. 
I am busy going through the book “Spring in action” and I need to try some of the examples out. I have looked at plenty of pages and nowhere can is see where I am going wrong. It must be something silly that I missed or overlooked.

1. I installed Spring source tool suite
2. Created a new java/maven project
3. Added a new applicationContext.xml bean definition file

The outline of the project looks as follows

[image]

I created my beans (vwCar & nissanCar that implements car interface) and where it comes to use them I have a main method in the app class. I need to create an application context.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathApplicationContext("src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml");
```

But I have difficulty creating the ApplicationContext. It gives me an error and code assist don’t work

Using code assist the only thing that it suggests is (Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> after typing app):
[image: Pressing Ctrl+Space after typing app]

If I just type it out I get an error

```
ApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type in class App.java
```

Is there something that I should import myself?

I can see an "S" on the project folder - doesn't this indicate that the project is already spring enabled?

[image: Spring indicator on project folder]

---------ADDED AFTER ALEX COMMENTED TO SUGGEST THAT I SHOULD ADD A MAVEN DEPENDENCY-------------

I added the missing dependency like Alex suggested but I don't know what the correct version is. If I look a the STS directory I see several files named ... 2.9.2

```
org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature_2.9.2.201205070117-RELEASE
```

but if I add the dependency with 2.9.2 i get the following error on my POM

```
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.9.2
```

My POM looks like below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>my.chrispie</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyMavenSpringProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MyMavenSpringProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I added the dependency like Alex indicated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Maven you should add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>

</dependency>
```

Where `${org.springframework-version}` should be replaced with the version you are using.

This will ensure that the Spring jars needed to get started are available to your application.

> It must be something silly that I missed or overlooked.

I think you'v just overlooked the dependency management functionality of Maven. Creating a Java/Maven project doesn't pull in the required Spring jars. If you used a template project from the STS landing page this would all have been setup for.

Comment: Thanx Alex, i surely didn't add that to my pom. Do you know where I can look for the correct version?

Comment: I did add the dependency and with what I think the version is based on the version I can see in the STS directory. It complains about the version no.

Comment: I would use version 3.1.1.RELEASE. The latest and greatest. :)

Comment: Thanks Alex... I had a look in the STS release management under the help docs for Maven Dependency Management. It indicates that the version shoul be <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>. I will try the 3.1.1. Thanks a lot for your help :)